# @Slf4j of lombok for logging is not working in file appender

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I am using `@Slf4j` of lombok for logging purposes in file appender. It's printing the logging message  when the server starts, i.e start up message. I am using Spring Data JPA and restful.
**But it's not printing the class level debug message in that logger file.**

In application.properties of spring-boot

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.config=/home/xyz/log4j.properties
```

In log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, R

#log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

# Enable application logging
log4j.category.com.evolvus= R

log4j.appender.R = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File = /home/xyz/Exptest.log
log4j.appender.R.Append = true
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
```

Comment: Can you post the code with the actual logging?

Answer (score 2):

It's working now, it's not due to that I have missed something in `application.properties` but due to I forget to add exclusion in `pom.xml`.

Actually by default spring boot have default logger if you want to add your's logger than we have use like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

or configure level for your packages:

```
logging.level.your.package=DEBUG
```

Comment: i already got the solution and which i already shared here.i hope you didn't    notice it.